# Chartboost and swift integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, chartboost

Ok, this is the first time I am trying to integrate chartboost and swift, so I will start from the beginning, maybe I missed something. First I have imported chartboost framework into my project, and then manually created the .h file, which I named BridgingHeader.h I added the needed import statements so that file looks like that now:

```
#ifndef appname_BridgingHeader_h
#define appname_BridgingHeader_h

#import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>
#import <Chartboost/CBNewsfeed.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>



#endif
```

I tried to build, everything went fine, but I noticed that it does not actually import this file. Hence I went to my project build settings, located Swift Compiler - Code Generation and found Objective-C Bridging Header and named it as appname/BridgingHeader.h . Now I am sure it did find the file and tried to import chartboost files, because I got 56 errors, of which all are in the chartboost files. Erros are such as "function definition is not allowed here" or "expected a type". The last error says that it failed to import bridging header. Anyone knows or has any ideas how to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I my problem.

1) UIKit import should be done as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#ifndef appname_BridgingHeader_h
#define appname_BridgingHeader_h

#import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>
#import <Chartboost/CBNewsfeed.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>



#endif
```

2) for the path, I should just went to the bridging file, in the file inspector copy the full path and paste it in the Swift Compiler - Code Generation.